# Performance of tests on Virtual machine VS local enviroment - REALLY SLOW ON VM

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, virtual-machine

I have one issue. I have maven project - JAVA,Selenium,Cucumber,Junit.
Im running tests with testrunner class and some oprtions in hooks on local enviroment test runs normally for few seconds - 25 +- but on VM is always problem when i tried to just open driver.get is it taking around 1min 30 sec just this one step can anyone know where can be problem ?? I honestly dont have any clue. Maybe perfomance of machine is not greatest.. but unfortunately i don't have access to that machine so im just executing it here via jenkins. If there is anything that can help or reduce the time i will be thankfull for any help.
And one more aditional info im running it on jenkins just with command: mvn -s .m2/settings.xml clean install -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@test"

Options:

```
> @Before
>     public WebDriver startBrowser(){
>         loggerManager.info("Test is starting...");
>         ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
>         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","src/main/resources/drivers/winChromedriver.exe");
>         //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/bin/chromedriver");
>         options.addArguments("--headless");
>         options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
>         options.addArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
>         options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
>         if (driver==null)
>         driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
>         driver.manage().window().maximize();
>         return driver;
>     }
```

Testrunner.class:

```
> @RunWith(Cucumber.class) @CucumberOptions(
>         features ={"src/test/resources/features/0001loginPage.feature","src/test/resources/features/0002passwordChange.feature",
>                 "src/test/resources/features/0003sbWorkflow.feature","src/test/resources/features/0004mmbSuccess.feature",
>                 "src/test/resources/features/0005report.feature"},
> 
>         glue = "stepDefinitions",
>         monochrome = true,
>         //tags ="",
>         plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/CucumberTestReports/CucumberTestReport.json",
> "html:target/CucumberTestReports/CucumberTestReport.html"} ) public
> class testRunner {
> 
> }
```

Comment: a VM is always going to be slower...  usually installing a ton of memory on the machine helps.

Comment: Yes i know but can it be that much slower ? like initialization running for 90 seconds seems too long to me but im just beginner in this topics.

Comment: it can be, yes... check the VM while it is running to see where the bottleneck might be.  You can adjust the VM settings to optimize it's performance.

Comment: Okay it was something diferent there was problem with loading images which was causing timeouts  so simply  adding: options.addArguments("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false"); fixed it not it is running really fast